# Bind the foreground color of a TextBlock to local variable

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

I want to bind the foreground color of a textblock to a local variable.
If the variable has no value (=null) than the foreground color should be black, if the variable is not null, than the foreground color should be black or whatever.
Is ist possible to solve that via Binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use value converter  first you define your converter like this

```
[ValueConversion (typeof(object), typeof(SolidColorBrush))]
public class ObjectToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

then in your XAML file you define converter as a resource

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ObjectToBrushConverter x:Key="ObjectToBrushConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

then you bind to your property and provide your converter

```
    <TextBox Name="textb" Text="Hello" Foreground="{Binding Path=MyObject,  Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ObjectToBrushConverter}}">
```

check out msdn on value converter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

of course assuming you defined your variable as public property and of type Object in this example